# Looking for the name of the image upscaling algorithm that worked with only the original image?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, image-processing, bitmap, bitmapimage

There was a recent paper / article that described an algorithm for upscaling an image. I can't find the name of that algorithm or the article but it worked with a single image (rather than multiple) to achieve really good results. If I saw the name of it I'd recognize it.

Once I find it I'm hoping there's a JavaScript, Java or ActionScript library. So any libraries specifically ActionScript or JS would help me narrow it down.

Comment: What you are looking for is **super resolution**.  There are **a lot** of research papers that have been produced over the last decade that talk about this.  Saying a "recent paper / article" is not enough.  There are at least a few papers that get written every few months that talk about it.  You can start by reading the Wikipedia article on the topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superresolution .  Pay specific attention to the bottom of the post.  There is an extensive list of papers that you can sift through and learn about it.  I can't comment on the availability of a JS library though.

Comment: Thanks. I remember now that this one worked with *one* image rather than multiple. I'll update the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SingleImageSR.html). It doesn't look like it has a name except, "SingleImageSR".

Comment: Check out this link as well.  More recent: https://sites.google.com/site/jbhuang0604/publications/struct_sr -  That method you referenced (I actually know the main author) is from 2009, but it's still very applicable and I have used it in the past.  What threw me off was when you said "recent".  If you didn't say "recent", what you posted is what I would have suggested first!

Comment: Yep. It was recent to me. I noticed it was from 2009 when I was searching and didn't think it was the same paper at first. This is really interesting.

Comment: It certainly is! Unfortunately I haven't found a JS library for you to use... but perhaps you can implement one of the two methods yourself.  Two very good JS libraries you can use that can serve as a backbone are JSFeat and tracking.js: http://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/, http://trackingjs.com/